# Trying to use typedef within a struct: why do I get an error, and is it a good idea in the first place?

Tags: c, struct, typedef, storage-class-specifier

I get this error when trying to declare an alias via 'typedef' from within a struct in my header file:

error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘typedef’

My initial intent was to test that the scope of the typedef was contained within the struct. This is so that I prevent the unwanted use of this alias if this header were to be included in another source file. If I move the offending line(the one starting with 'typedef') outside the struct and before it, the code compiles.

However, I don't understand why I couldn't call typedef from within the struct, and why I get the aforementioned error instead.

Furthermore, I'm unsure whether this practice is actually necessary. What are the merits of restricting the alias, if any?

```
#ifndef STUDENT_H
#define STUDENT_H

typedef struct{

    typedef char* string;
    string name;
    int id;

} Student;

#endif
```

I expect the code to compile, but instead I get the error message:

> error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘typedef’

Comment: C++ supports this. C does not. In C++, classes form their own name spaces—everything inside the class is part of it and can be referred to using various C++ syntax. C does not have any syntax for referring to things inside a structure except for structure members accessed with the `.` or `->` operators. It does not have `::`. C developed with a largely global name space (structure members used to be in one name space; now they are in a separate space for each structure type) and never developed features for types within structures.

Answer (score 6):

You cannot have a `typedef` inside a `typedef`.

You can have:

```
typedef char* string;
```

and then use it:

```
typedef struct{
    string name;
    int id;
} Student;
```

Be careful that `string` is just a pointer, it must "point" to allocated memory before you can use it (especially before writing to it).

---

> However, I don't understand why I couldn't call typedef from within the struct

That is how C worked since ever, and everybody was just fine with it. You will have to learn to accept this "limitation".

Comment: @Aiman you cannot have a typedef inside a struct, period. No matter if the struct is inside a typedef or not. A struct does not create any kind of typedef scope, so even that that was allowed by the grammar, it would be useless and confusing. The only kind of scope/namespace created by a struct is for its **field names** -- and even that is a later development -- in the pre-standard K&R C, you could access field defined in a struct via a pointer to another struct (that's the reason for the prefixes in the fields of structs in many legacy interfaces -- eg. the `pw_` in `struct passwd`.

Answer (score 3):

Opposite to C++ C is very restricted language. Within a structure data members may not have storage-class specifiers (`typedef`, `extern`, `static`, `_Thread_local`, `auto`, `register`) and `typedef` as you can see is considered in C as a storage-class specifier.

You can place the typedef before the structure definition like

```
typedef char* string;

typedef struct{
    string name;
    int id;
} Student;
```

and use the typedef throughout your program.

But take into account that if you will write for example

```
const string s = "Hello Aiman";
```

it does not mean the same as

```
const char * s = "Hello Aiman";
```

It does mean

```
char * const s = "Hello Aiman";
```

That is it is not the string literal pointed to by the pointer that is constant. It is the pointer itself that is constant.

Consider the following demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef char * string;

void f( const string s )
{
    *s = 'B';
    *( s + 1 ) = 'y';
    *( s + 2 ) = 'e';
    *( s + 3 ) = '\0';

    //  The statement below issues compilation error
    //  "assignment of read-only parameter 's'"
    //  s = "Hello";
}

int main( void )
{
    char s[] = "Hello";

    puts( s );

    f( s );

    puts( s );
}
```

Its output is

```
Hello
Bye
```

That is within the function the string pointed to by the pointer `s` can be changed but the pointer itself can not be changed.

So maybe it is better not to introduce such a typedef because using such a typedef in declarations like

```
const string s
```

will confuse readers of the code.